# Oracle connection fails standalone but works fine when application is run from Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, msbuild

I have a .Net application written in C#. The application uses oracle (Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core).

When I run the application directly from Visual Studio 2017 - it works fine and I can read the data, but when I try to run it as a standalone application (.exe) it fails with the following error:

**FATAL ERROR: ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified**

Any ideas what can be wrong here? I tried to google it but did not really find anything.
Thanks.

Comment: See https://edstevensdba.wordpress.com/2018/09/19/troubleshooting-ora-12154/: it is very detailed and very good but you need to understand how Oracle Net (aka "TNS") works.

Comment: Most likely your stand-alone .exe is operating in an environment that does not allow it to locate its sqlnet.ora and tnsnames.ora files.  That would include the environment variable ORACLE_HOME, from sqlnet then derives the location of the two files.

Comment: Check the Debug/Release folder of exe and see the last time it was updated.  Also any other project that are referenced.   Issue like this usually occur when in VS you are running the debug executable and running the release version (which doesn't have the latest updates) from outside VS.

Comment: @jdweng everything is up-to-date. Both in Debug and Release folder.

Comment: Try creating a shortcut for VS and then open VS by right click shortcut and select Run As Admin.